# Type error .then() is not a function in webpack 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack-2

I am using webpack 2 and angular js in apps, when i try to call function on button click, I am getting error **TypeError: myContract.sendFunds(...).then is not a function**.below is my code.

```
app.controller('sendfundscntrl',function ($scope) {  
    //get  list of accounts
    $scope.accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

    //withdrawl function
    $scope.widthdrwal = function (address,amount) {
        //I have all my solidity function in myContract using ABI          
        myContract.sendFunds(
            amount,
            address{from:web3.eth.accounts[0]}
        ).then(function (newBalance) {
            console.log(newBalance);
            $scope.transfer_sucess="Its success", $scope.apply();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            $scope.has_Errors="It didnt work"
            $scope.apply();
        })
    }
});

//Solidity Contract
function sendFunds(uint amount,address receiver) public returns(uint) {
    if (this.balance >= amount) {
        if (!receiver.send(amount)) {
            revert();
        }

        return this.balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sendFunds` need to return a promise

Comment: how to return promise

Comment: show `sendFunds` function

Comment: i have update code

Comment: How you init your contract's ABI ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reach your first condition, it won't return a promise.

You guess you need something like this:

```
//Solidity Contract
function sendFunds(uint amount, address receiver) public returns(uint) {
    if (this.balance >= amount) {
        if (!receiver.send(amount)) {
            revert();
        }
    }

    return this.balance;
}
```

Comment: still same error TypeError: myContract.sendFunds(...).then is not a function

Comment: I advise you then to find you promise. Print some of your variables (`console.log(this);` inside sendFunds, or `console.log(myContract);`). I have not enough infos to help you. Maybe `return this;` will works, but this is a pure guess.

Comment: anyways thanks for your time,i am checking,even i used return this its not working.